# How to determine the matrix $C$ in $C=P^{-1} A P$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In this theorem, I sometimes find it a little puzzling how to determine $C$ if $A$ is not given, when I am only provided with the eigenvalues and vectors.

I know I can pick either of $a + bi$  or $a - bi$ to form the $P$ matrix and its inverse, however, it seems that the formula $P^{-1}AP$ produce different $C$,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and I have difficulty knowing which one to use, especially when I don't have enough time to test. Is there a rule of thumb to determine which $C$,from the two above, is correct to use corresponding to the either eigenvalues?

> **Theorem 9**
>
> Let $A$ be a real $2 \times 2$ matrix with a complex eigenvalue
>   $\lambda = a - bi\ (b \neq 0)$ and an associated eigenvector
>   $\mathbf{v}$ in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$. Then
>
> $$ A = PCP^{-1}, \quad \text{where} \quad P = \begin{bmatrix}
>  \operatorname{Re} \mathbf{v} & \operatorname{Im} \mathbf{v}
>  \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad C = \begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b &
>  a \end{bmatrix} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, given the eigenvalues and their eigenvectors, there are 2 possible matrices for $ 2 \times 2 $ matrix. In general, there could be $ n! $ $ n \times n $ matrices.

There is no way you can recover the original matrix just from the eigenvalues and their associated vectors alone.

Comment: @ Andrew Au Just in the case of 2 x 2, and given a - bi, can you determine C right away? according to the theorem, it is$ \begin{pmatrix}
        a & -b   \\
        b & a \\
        \end{pmatrix} $  but it seems that this is not always the case, sometimes I get this same matrix when I use a+bi instead of a- bi for some matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can determine your $C$: I guess your confusion comes from whether to pick 
$$
\lambda=a+ib \text{ or }  \lambda=a-ib
$$
but in fact - if you stick with your theorem and the used notation - you have no choice, you need to take the second representation of the eigenvalue which is
$$
\lambda=a-ib
$$
which gives you the proper $a$ and $b$ for the matrix $C$. Let's have a look at an example
$$
\lambda=1-i\equiv a-ib\implies a =1,b=1
$$
and matrix $$C=\begin{pmatrix}1 &-1\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
now you just need the corresponding eigenvector $v$ to compute $P$. So it really just boils down to a comparison of coefficients.